# Why should I use aggregators functions with having not where?

Tags: sql

Why should I write this:

```
Having count(id) > 1
```

instead of this:

```
Where count(id) > 1
```

Is this just for English language?

I think if the programmer that invented where clause could made it accept aggregators

Or is there a reason for that? In loading the data or anything like that?

Comment: Not at all.  The first works and is proper SQL.  The second doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that SQL evaluates items in a certain order e.g.

- Identify the tables in question
- Apply the where clause to narrow the rows
- Take values from the columns
- Apply aggregates (group by clauses)
- Apply aggregate limits (having clauses)
- Apply sorting (order by clauses)

If you tried to evaluate an aggregate in a "where" clause it literally wouldn't make sense as it needs to apply the "where" clause before aggregation.

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE` operates on rows, `HAVING` operates on collections of rows ("groups"). Aggregate functions cannot be used on single rows, that just would not make any sense.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) states:

> group (aggregate) functions that operate on sets of values [...] If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.